# How to show 3D object with textures in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, 3d, blender, arkit

I am playing with an ARKit and so far I am successful, but I have a problem with 3D graphic (as I don't know anything about it).

Every object I download from sites like TurboSquid is without textures in Xcode and even in Blender (or shows without textures).

I just need to get an object (the best would be .dae) with applied textures on it.

Can you please explain to my like to a three years old child what am I missing?

Thank you.

EDIT:

This is the model which is moving with camera even when I setup his location:

[Table from TurboSquid](https://www.turbosquid.com/FullPreview/Index.cfm/ID/410486)

```
let treeScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/table2/table2.scn")
let treeNode = treeScene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "table2", recursively: true)
treeNode?.position = position

sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(treeNode!)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm also starting to learn ARKit and this is how i did it.

Some of the 3d models comes with textures in png files, which can then be copied to art.scnassets. The select the dae model and got the node that you want to apply the texture. In the Material Inspector in right hand side apply texture correspondingly.

Or

You can create a SCNMaterial using the texture and apply it to the node programmatically.

```
let material = SCNMaterial()
material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "texture.png")

//Create the the node and apply texture
objectNode?.geometry?.materials = [material]
```

Try this as a trial

https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/free-missile-3d-model/595524

Apply the texture in diffuse (in Material Inspector).

Comment: Thank you for a great tip! So do I have to download just a 3D models with included textures? Why are there models without it? Can it be exported from Blender somehow?

Comment: When exporting a textured  model in Blender to a DAE file, you need to tick the option to save the materials.   I would sometimes forget to tick that option.

Comment: @M.Bedi Thank you very much ;) One last question. I added four models without any problem, then I applied textures. But two models are wierd. I am setting position for every model the same (get the position of point in SCNVector3), but two models are just following my camera. So no matter where I touch the screen, they always appear on the same spot and just follows the camera. So if I move, the object (model) moves too. Other models are ok and stay on their positions.

Comment: @Boomerange : Can you post your code to check. Also worldtracking works with A9 or above chipset device.

Comment: @M.Bedi As I wrote, everything works great on other models. But not on two of them. The code is above.

Comment: I just tried to download the dae file but I keep getting errors from the web-site.